# Show an inequality by Vasile Cirtoaje already proved by Mitsuhiro Miyagi & Yusuke Nishizawa

Tags: derivatives, inequality, power-series

It's an attempt to show the inequality in [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20derivative%20%28ln%28%28a%29x%5E%28-2%281-x%29%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%28%282a%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%20%28ln%28%28a%29%281-x%29%5E%28-2%28x%29%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%28%282a%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29) (already proved see the last link).

Let $0.5\leq x<1$ an $k\geq 5$ then we have :

$$x^{\left(2\left(1-x\right)\right)^{k}}+(1-x)^{\left(2\left(x\right)\right)^{k}}\leq 1\quad (I)$$

My attempt :

The problem can be considered as :

$$r(x)=\left((1-x)^{-\left(2\left(x\right)\right)^{k}}-1\right)\left((x)^{-\left(2\left(1-x\right)\right)^{k}}-1\right)\geq1$$

First lemma :

Let $1< x\leq 2$ then we have :

$$1+\left(\frac{\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}\right)^{\frac{\ln\left(64\right)}{3}}-x\leq 0$$

We apply this lemma to have :

$$r(x)\geq \left(\frac{\left(\ln\left((x)^{-\left(2\left(1-x\right)\right)^{k}}\right)\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}\right)^{\frac{\ln\left(64\right)}{3}} \left((1-x)^{-\left(2\left(x\right)\right)^{k}}-1\right)\geq 1$$

The intermediate inequality is also :

$$\ln\left((1-x)^{-\left(2\left(x\right)\right)^{k}}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\left(\ln\left((x)^{-\left(2\left(1-x\right)\right)^{k}}\right)\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}\right)^{\frac{\ln\left(64\right)}{3}}}+1\right)\geq 0$$

For that we introduce the function :

$$f(x)=\ln\left((1-x)^{-\left(2\left(x\right)\right)^{k}}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\left(\ln\left((x)^{-\left(2\left(1-x\right)\right)^{k}}\right)\right)}{\ln\left(2\right)}\right)^{\frac{\ln\left(64\right)}{3}}}+1\right)$$

The derivative is not pretty I don't expose it here but I give you a link : [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+derivative+1%2F%28%28ln%28%28a%29x%5E%28-2%281-x%29%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%28%282a%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2B1%29%2B+1%2F%28%28ln%28%28a%29%281-x%29%5E%28-2%28x%29%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%28%282a%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2B1%29)

Now a power series at second order ($x=0.5$) is sufficient to conclude that the derivative is positive on $[0.5,1)$.

### Second way

Second lemma

Let $1< x$ and $a>2$ then we have :

$$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{\left(\ln\left(ax\right)^{c}-\ln\left(a\right)^{c}\right)}{\left(\ln\left(2a\right)^{c}-\ln\left(a\right)^{c}\right)}-x\right)\leq 0$$

We can find $c$ as $f'(2)=0$.The definition of $c$ involves the Lambert's function.

Proof :

We have :

$$f'(x)=\frac{c(\ln(ax))^{c-1}}{x\left(\ln\left(2a\right)^{c}-\ln\left(a\right)^{c}\right)}-1$$

We substitute $x=\frac{1}{y^{c-1}a}$

The inequality have the form :

$$\ln(u)u=p$$

Wich is just the Lambert's function . The rest is easy .

End of the proof .

As partial answer for the second lemma we can use the inequality :

Let $a>b>d$,$a>c>d$,$s<t$ and $s,t\neq0$ then we have :

$$\frac{e^{as}-e^{bs}}{e^{cs}-e^{ds}}<\frac{e^{at}-e^{bt}}{e^{ct}-e^{dt}}\quad(T)$$

And then evaluate a limit .

The inequality can be found in the Dictionary of Inequalities second edition by Professor Peter Bullen (2015) p85.

The inequality above is a consequence of the MVT.

Now we apply twice the second lemma and we start by introducing (see the reference) :

$$f(x)=((\ln((a)b^{-(2(1-b))^x}))^c-(\ln(a))^c) ((\ln((a)(1-b)^{-(2(b))^x}))^c-(\ln(a))^c)$$

The derivative is :

$$f'(x)=c(u(x)+v(x))$$

Where :

$$u(x)=\left(2-2b\right)^{x}\cdot\ln(2\left(1-b)\right)\cdot\ln(b)\cdot\left((\ln(a))^{c}-\left(\ln(a\cdot\left(1-b\right)^{-(2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a\cdot(b)^{-\left(2-2b\right)^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}$$

$$v(x)=2^{x}\cdot b^{x}\cdot\ln(1-b)\cdot\ln(2b)\cdot\left((\ln(a))^{c}-\left(\ln(a\cdot b^{-(2-2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a\cdot(1-b)^{-2^{x}b^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}$$

So we can choose a value for $a$ by example $a=10^{10}$ with $c$ defined above ($f'(2)=0$) and complete it with the Bernoulli's inequality .With regard to the derivative above we have $0.5\leq b<1$ , $a,c$ as in the lemma and $x\geq 1$.If we don't use Bernoulli's inequality then we have $a\to\infty$ and $c\to\infty$.Remains to show that the derivative is positives with these constraints .We can also take the logarithm on both side but it doesn't seem very useful.

A bit of Algebra and we need to show something like:

$$\frac{\left(2-2b\right)^{x}\cdot\ln(2\left(1-b)\right)\cdot\ln(b)}{2^{x}\cdot b^{x}\cdot\ln(1-b)\cdot\ln(2b)}\geq^{?}-\left(\frac{\left((\ln(a))^{c}-\left(\ln(a\cdot\left(1-b\right)^{-(2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a\cdot(b)^{-\left(2-2b\right)^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}}{\left((\ln(a))^{c}-\left(\ln(a\cdot b^{-(2-2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a\cdot(1-b)^{-2^{x}b^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}}\right)^{-1}\quad(U)$$

So there is a possibility to use the inequality $(T)$.Another good way is to choose $c$ as a natural number and factorize .This way have to be completed with Bernoulli's inequality .

A good idea is to find a refinement like ($\alpha>1$):

$$g(x)\geq \alpha f(x)\geq h(x)$$

Where :

$$g(x)=\frac{\left(2-2b\right)^{x}\cdot\ln(2\left(1-b)\right)\cdot\ln(b)}{2^{x}\cdot b^{x}\cdot\ln(1-b)\cdot\ln(2b)}$$

$$f\left(x\right)=-\left(\left(\frac{\left((\ln(a^{(2b)^{x}}))^{c}-\left(\ln(a^{\left((2b)^{x}\right)}\cdot\left(1-b\right)^{-(2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a^{\left(2-2b\right)^{x}}\cdot(b)^{-\left(2-2b\right)^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}}{\left((\ln(a^{(2-2b)^{x}}))^{c}-\left(\ln(a^{(2-2b)^{x}}\cdot b^{-(2-2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a^{2^{x}b^{x}}\cdot(1-b)^{-2^{x}b^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}}\right)^{-1}\right)$$

And :

$$h(x)=-\left(\frac{\left((\ln(a))^{c}-\left(\ln(a\cdot\left(1-b\right)^{-(2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a\cdot(b)^{-\left(2-2b\right)^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}}{\left((\ln(a))^{c}-\left(\ln(a\cdot b^{-(2-2b)^{x}})\right)^{c}\right)\left(\ln(a\cdot(1-b)^{-2^{x}b^{x}})\right)^{\left(c-1\right)}}\right)^{-1}$$

Question :

With all my work how to show the inequality $(I)$ ?

References :

[1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20derivative%20%28ln%28%28a%29x%5E%28-2%281-x%29%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%28%282a%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%20%28ln%28%28a%29%281-x%29%5E%28-2%28x%29%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%28%282a%29%29%5Ec-ln%28a%29%5Ec%29) Vasile Cirtoaje, "Proofs of three open inequalities with power-exponential functions",

The Journal of Nonlinear Sciences and its Applications (2011), Volume: 4, Issue: 2, page 130-137.
https://eudml.org/doc/223938

Miyagi, M., Nishizawa, Y. Proof of an open inequality with double power-exponential functions. J Inequal Appl 2013,

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1029-242X-2013-468

Comment: For the case $n=5$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+derivative+%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Cleft%281-x%5Cright%29%5E%7B-%5Cleft%282x%5Cright%29%5E%7B5%7D%7D%5Cright%29-%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cln%5Cleft%28%28x%29%5E%7B-%5Cleft%282%5Cleft%281-x%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%5E%7B5%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%7D%7B%5Cln%5Cleft%282%5Cright%29%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5Cleft%2864%5Cright%29%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7D%2B1%5Cright%29++at+x%3D0.5

Comment: We have a big trick : in the derivative https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+-%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cln%5Cleft%28%28x%29%5E%7B-%5Cleft%282%5Cleft%281-x%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%5E%7Bk%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%7D%7B%5Cln%5Cleft%282%5Cright%29%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%5Cleft%2864%5Cright%29%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7D%2B1%5Cright%29 we can replace the $+1$ by $2^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\alpha}$ with a judicious choice of $\alpha>0$

Comment: We can improve the lemma see WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+%28%28ln%281.5x%29%5Ec-ln%281.5%29%5Ec%29%2F%28ln%283%29%5Ec-ln%281.5%29%5Ec%29%29-x%2B1%3D0+at+x%3D2

Comment: For the equality $f'(2)=0$ I don't know if there is an analitycall solution .Instead of we can use the Lagrange Inversion Theorem.

Comment: In fact $f'(2)=0$ gives the inequality $u\ln(y)+vy+w=0$ .It's just the Lambert's function.